# st_crop crops a shapefile weirdly

Tags: r, r-sf

I am quite new in the sf package. I would like to work on a map with distance calculation.

I downloaded the europe shapefile (https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-coastline-for-analysis-1/gis-data/europe-coastline-shapefile)

And I tried to zoom it by croping:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# Help:
# https://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=28604

# https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-coastline-for-analysis-1/gis-data/europe-coastline-shapefile
europe <-  "~/Dropbox/Boulot/BIODIVERSA/Data/Shapefiles/european_shapefile/europe_whole/Europe_coastline_poly.shp" %>% st_read()

st_agr(europe) = "constant"
```

Observed map (i.e. not cropped):
[image]

I looked at it I saw the bounding box:

```
Simple feature collection with 71520 features and 1 field
Attribute-geometry relationship: 1 constant, 0 aggregate, 0 identity
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 943609.8 ymin: -375446 xmax: 7601958 ymax: 6825119
Projected CRS: ETRS89_LAEA_Europe
First 10 features:
   Id                       geometry
1   0 POLYGON ((7107204 408030.5,...
2   0 POLYGON ((7101776 408237.2,...
3   0 POLYGON ((7101975 408397.5,...
4   0 POLYGON ((7104733 411690.7,...
5   0 POLYGON ((7103793 412466.7,...
6   0 POLYGON ((7089504 419781.4,...
7   0 POLYGON ((7067634 431183, 7...
8   0 POLYGON ((7020099 431621.1,...
9   0 POLYGON ((7024019 431609.5,...
10  0 POLYGON ((7066881 432938.8,...
```

So based on that bounding box figures I tried to crop the europe map:

```
europe_crop <- st_crop(europe, y = c(xmin = 600609.8, ymin = 600446, xmax = 6001958, ymax = 5005119))
plot(europe_crop)
```

Same map. No zoom at all. So I tried to understand by doing a locator, I found some very low coordinates. So I run:

```
europe_crop <- st_crop(europe, y = c(xmin = 0.28, ymin = 0.33, xmax = 0.43, ymax = 0.77))
plot(europe_crop)
Error in plot_sf(x, ...) : 
  NA value(s) in bounding box. Trying to plot empty geometries?
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Seems to small.

```
europe_crop <- st_crop(europe, y = c(xmin = 1, ymin = 1, xmax = 5, ymax = 5))
```

Same results... Cant' understand the behavior of the st_crop function?
If I want to zoom for instance on France, how do I do ?

Thanks a million !

Comment: Did you double check the x-coordinates of your cropping box? They're entirely outside the range of your Europe spatial object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 europe_crop <- st_crop(europe, y = c(
    xmin = 600609.8,
    ymin = 600446,
    xmax = 6001958,
    ymax = 5005119))
```

...has done something:

```
> st_bbox(europe)
     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
 943609.8 -375446.0 7601958.5 6825119.3 
> st_bbox(europe_crop)
     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
 943609.8  600446.0 6001958.0 5005119.0
```

But `xmin` hasn't changed because you're trying to crop to an xmin less than that (600609.8 < 943609). `st_crop` can't expand the extent when cropping because there's no features there.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman! that makes totally sense now ! Again thanks a lot!